# Why doesn't my component render when I redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm conditionally rendering a redirect like this

```
render() {
  if (condition) { 
   return(<someComponent />) 
} else {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Redirect push to="/newRoute" />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

but my component does render when the route redirects. How can i pass it some props to cause the component to render?

edit: heres some more context

`index.js`

```
export const init = () => {
  return render(
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
</MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('app')
  )
}

init()
```

and then I've got a file that is a much longer version of this

`routes.js`

```
 export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRedirect to='/in'/>
    <Route path='in' component={Authentication(MainPage)}>
      <Route path='/newRoute' component={newComponent}/>
    </Route>
 </Route>
)
```

Comment: Need more information. What exactly os happening right now?  Is your if condition working or else and which component you need to render?  <someComponent/> or redirect?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My if condition is working fine. The browser updates the route, but the actual component itself does not render.

Comment: Can you please share actual component entire JS file too?  What I understand is at current stage you have make sure that your render method and if condition are working properly and as per your expectations you "someComponent"  is being returned but its not rendering, right?

Comment: Where is `<Route path="/newRoute"/>` defined, if at all?

Comment: I have updated my original post with some more context